# Playing music in Pygame causes an assertion failure message

Tags: python, audio, pygame, assertion

I'm having trouble playing music in Pygame. I type:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3")

pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
```

but I get this message:

```
Assertion failed!

Program: C\Python33\pythonw.exe

File:..\..\audio\mpegtoraw.cpp
Line: 505

Expression: audio->rawdatawriteoffset > len
```

Then it tells me to see C++ documentation. It's not the loading of the music, it's the playing that causes the message. I tried different music files too.

Comment: Have you tried this with a different mp3 file?  The error suggests to me that your mp3 file might be corrupted, because it's overflowing a buffer while being converted to raw audio samples.  (This could also be a bug or an unsupported mp3 feature of some kind in mpegtoraw.cpp.)

Comment: I've tried a few others but they all give the same message. Only one 'worked' in that it didn't show the error, but no sound played.

Comment: Is your bit version of pygame and python matching?

Comment: Yes, they both seem to be the 32-bit version.

Comment: Does anyone have anymore advice? I've continued but would still like some music!

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, I had the same error but I tried playing different mp3s and got success with one. I downloaded a sample mp3 from [here](http://www.tonycuffe.com/samples.htm)

So, it seems not all mp3 files are playable.

Hope it helps :)