# c++ error on a python progam

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, pygame

in my python program a c++ error pops up. i know that my program is glitchy and has bugs but why is there a error with c++

```
Assertion failed!
Program: C:\Python33\pythonw.exe
File: .-\--\audio\mpegtoraw.cpp
Line: 505
Expression: audio->rawdatawriteoffset > len
For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts
(Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)
```

---

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)
BGC = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 80
PLAYERMOVERATE = 5
countBy = 10

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitShoot(playerRect, shoot):
    if playerRect.colliderect(shoot):
        return True
    return False

def baddieHasHitShoot(baddieRect, shoot):
    if baddieRect.colliderect(shoot):
        return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,48)
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mothers Day')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('gameicon.gif'))

gameStartSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gamestart.wav')
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameend.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mp3')

playerImage = pygame.image.load('starship.bmp')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('enemy.bmp')
baddieRect = baddieImage.get_rect()
shootImage = pygame.image.load('shoot.bmp')
shootRect = shootImage.get_rect()


drawText('Star Trek', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 2.5), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3.75) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()

def fire(shoot):
    shootRect.topleft = ((playerRect / 2), 101)
    shootRect.move_ip(5, 1)

topScore = 10000
while True:

    SS = []
    score = 10000
    playerRect.topleft = (0, 100)
    moveUp = moveDown = False
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while True:
        score -= countBy
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == ord(' '):
                    fire
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord(' '):
                    fire
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False


        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)


        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, screen, 10, 40)

        screen.blit(playerImage, playerRect)
        screen.blit(shootImage, shootRect)
        screen.blit(baddieImage, baddieRect)
        pygame.display.update()


        if playerHasHitShoot(playerRect, baddieRect):
            score = 0 
        break

        if baddieHasHitShoot(baddieRect, shoot):
            if score > topScore:
                score = topscore
            break
        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gameOverSound.play()
    drawText('GAME OVER', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, screen, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()
    gameOverSound.stop()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing music in Pygame causes an assertion failure message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393526/playing-music-in-pygame-causes-an-assertion-failure-message)

Comment: It's a bug in the Python interpreter.

Comment: @icktoofay How did you get it to let you mark as a duplicate of that? When I try it says that the other question doesn't have any upvoted or accepted answers.

Comment: @Barmar: I sort of slid around that rule by upvoting the answer, marking as a duplicate, and then unupvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Python music player, it has trouble converting some MP3 files. The only solution appears to be to try a different file.